# What is the smallest integer $p$ for which $\sqrt {480p}$ is an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Full Question: 180 can be expressed as a product of its prime factors as $180=2^2\times3^2\times5$, find the smallest integer value of p for which $\sqrt {480p}$ is an integer

I'm stuck here

$$\sqrt{480}=\sqrt{2^5\times 3\times 5}$$

So how to do next? I'm referencing myself to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176965/237803 but I'm confused.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lulu, The question is the title.

Comment: There is no question in the title, it just stops mid sentence.

Comment: Are you working with $180$ or $480$?  If the latter, why tell us the factoring of $180$?

Comment: Looks like phone and desktop show significantly different. In my iPhone the full question is in title. I've added the full question in description too.

Comment: Well... $p=0$. :)

Comment: Seems a bit more number theory-y, than linear linear algebra

Comment: @Prince M, sorry, I don't know any Math categories. Change it to whatever is correct. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, goodluck! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $p=0$ you get $\sqrt{480*0}=\sqrt{0}=0$.
If $p\neq 0$ then notice that $480=2^5*3*5$ so you need that every exponent be an even number, then $p=2*3*5=30$.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a number to be a perfect square, all its prime factors must be raise to an even power i.e. $b^{2n}$.

So $p = 2*3*5$ because $480p=2^6*3^2*5^2$ => $\sqrt{480p}=\sqrt{2^6*3^2*5^2}=2^3*3*5$

That's because $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$, $(ab)^x=a^x*b^x$ and `$(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$,
so $\sqrt{b_{1}^{2n_{1}}*b_{2}^{2n_{2}}*...}=(b_{1}^{2n_{1}}*b_{2}^{2n_{2}}*...)^{1/2}=b_{1}^{2n_{1}/2}*b_{2}^{2n_{2}/2}*...$ where $n_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are integers

Comment: Wait, I don't understand why p=2x3x5 . Shouldn't p = 2^3, according to the reference? (since it is the only odd one not perfect square root) Your last paragraph explanation I completely don't understand.

Comment: $p= 2^3$ would yield $\sqrt{2^8*3*5}$ which isn't a perfect square.  $p$ needs to be enough to make the factors of 2,3,5 even powers and the least such number to do so.  So $2^5*3*5$ needs the become $2^6*3^2*5^2$ so we need $p = 2^13^15^1$.